# Access local file in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, electron

I have a js app (packaged with Electron) in which I wish to load a yaml file. The following works when I have packaged the app since the `app.getAppPath()` gives me access to the `app.asar` file, but in development it returns the path `\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\resources\default_app.asar`.

```
fs.readFileSync(`${app.getAppPath()}/src/app/data/items.yml`, 'utf8')
```

Is there any way to get around this? Should my yaml file not be placed in the same directory as the rest of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `path` module together with the `__dirname` built-in to construct file paths to assets relative to your source files, the relative paths won't change between development and packaged builds. For example, assuming the following directory structure:

```
src/
  app/
    browser/
      main.js
    data/
      items.yml
```

You should reference `items.yml` in `main.js` like so:

```
path.join(__dirname, '..', 'data', 'items.yml')
```

Comment: I try to do `path.join(__dirname, '.', 'items.en.yml')` to get the file from `data.js` in the same directory. That returns `\items.yml` and when I use that with `fs.readFileSync` it tries to retrieve a file located under `C:\items.yml` which is of course no where to be found. Am I using the fs module wrong or how would/should you get the data from the yml file?

Comment: @schwifty If you want to access a file in the same directory then it'd be `path.join(__dirname, 'items.en.yml')`. However, even with what you wrote I don't think `path.join()` should be returning just `\items.yml` unless `__dirname` is empty, so check what `__dirname` is actually set to inside `data.js`.

Comment: `__dirname` just gives me `/` - I'm on Windows at the moment if that makes any difference.

Comment: Are you using some sort of module bundler? Did you `require()` `data.js` or load it by some other means?

Comment: Yes, it's bundled with webpack and the `data.js` is imported in `src/app/index.js`

Comment: You need to fix your webpack config, I think `node: { __dirname: false, __filename: false }` should do the trick. See https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/blob/v0.10.0/webpack.config.electron.js#L35 for an example.